# Запуск скрипта mySQL в intellij idea

Tags: java, mysql, sql, база-данных, intellij-idea

[image: Скрин]

Есть проект со своей базой данных MySQL, необходимо запустить скрипт в IntelliJ IDEA. База данных с Workbench получилось синхронизировать, но  сам скрипт в IDE запустить не получается — попадаю в Run/Debug Configurations. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что именно необходимо сделать, IntelliJ IDEA есть консоль для работы с bd. Там пробовали  ?

Comment: Вопрос снят! Вследствие моего незнания, решил проблему с помощью Tomcat ! Разобрался =)